# Что такое this.props.children?

Tags: reactjs

Здравствуйте!

Помогите разобраться с this.props.children

Во всех компонентах дерева оно у меня undefined. Поиграл с примерами из react-select - в одних случаях это свойство есть, в других нет.
Как я понимаю, дети создаются в методе render. Если в компоненте

```
render() {
    return <div/>
}
```

div должен попасть в children?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

this.props - это то, что передается от родителя

Если в рендере написать

```
<MyComp>
    {'123'}
</MyComp>
```

то в MyComp появится this.props.children '123'

Answer (score 0):

Классы - они же функции. Если в функции пустой return, то при выводе результата вывода в консоль - будет undefined. Аналогичто с классами, в частности с методом Render - если внутри html тега нет други тегов или текста, то и children будет undefined